# How to make my program have an outofbounds exception

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

I am trying to catch an outofbounds exception in my program that creates a random number from 1 to 50 and the user guesses that number. The problem that I am facing is that whenever I enter a number that is past the maximum it doesn't catch it as an exception and displays the appropriate message but instead displays a different message.

This is what I have currently

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int count = 0, ran, min = 1, max = 50;
    int ent = 0;
    ran = (int)(Math.random()*(max-min)) + min;
    System.out.println("Guess a number from 1 to 50.");
  try{
      do{
          ent = in.nextInt();
          count++;
          if(ent > ran){
              System.out.println("Too high. Try again.");
          }else if(ent < ran){
              System.out.println("Too low. Try again.");
          }
      }while(ent!=ran);
  }
  catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException ex){
      System.out.println("Guess a number from 1 to 50!");
  }
  catch(InputMismatchException ex){
      System.out.println("Invalid input");
  }
```

I also want to continue the program even after catching an exception but whenever I try to change it the result ends in an infinite loop

```
boolean done = false;
    while(!done){
    System.out.println("Guess a number from 1 to 50.");
  try{
          ent = in.nextInt();
          count++;
          if(ent > ran){
              System.out.println("Too high. Try again.");
          }else if(ent < ran){
              System.out.println("Too low. Try again.");
          }
          done = true;
  }
  catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException ex){
      System.out.println("Guess a number from 1 to 50!");
  }
  catch(InputMismatchException ex){
      System.out.println("Invalid input");
  }
}
```

this is what I tried to do

Comment: What makes you think that any of the lines inside the try block would be throwing that exception? From the javadoc of that exception: **Thrown to indicate that an index of some sort (such as to an array, to a string, or to a vector) is out of range.
** ... you aren't accessing any sort of list/array/... here, so why do you expect THAT exception to ever occur?

Comment: So, if you **want** that such an exception gets thrown (which would be a MISUSE of it), then you would need something like `if (ent < 1 || ent > 50) throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException()` after you asked the user to enter the value. Also note: your loop variable DONE is never changed, so your code will keep looping.

Comment: You need to handle the  case `ent==ran`, too. And ideally, you tell the user: "when you enter 0, you give up, and the loop ends, too" and make that happen.

Comment: ahh that was something mssing i think there was supposed to be done = true at the end.

Answer (score 0):

You should not employ Exceptions for flow control - use a loop with a if-condition that makes sense.  You can bake it into the while-loop condition but in this case the return short-circuits the loop if the guess is valid.

```
public int getGuess(Scanner in) {
  while (true) {
   System.out.printf("Enter a value between %d and %d", min, max).println();
    int guess = in.nextInt();
    if (guess < min || guess > max) {
      System.out.printf("Guess must be between %d and %d, try again", min, max).println();
    } else {
      return guess;
    }
  }
}
```